# how to implement Drag and Drop in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, drag-and-drop

I'm looking in this tutorial [GWT DND](http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.DragDropDemo/DragDropDemo.html#InsertPanelExample)

I want this Demo 5 to implement in my project, but I am confused as to how to implement it, as there are different classes for the source code:

*Source code: InsertPanelExample.java, VerticalPanelDropController.java, VerticalPanelWithSpacer.java, HorizontalPanelDropController.java, PickupDragController.java)*

Do we need to take all these around 5 source codes to implement this functionality, and how do we merge these different codes?

Answer (score 0):

The source code of the demo can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/source/browse/DragDrop/demo/)
But if i were you I would write my own library elevating from it.